# MUI Datetimepicker changing value by using dropdown select

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datetimepicker

I'm using react datetimepicker and going to use selector to change the value. but it's not changing when i pick an option (for example: i choose 6 month, it will add the finish date for 6 months). Here's my code

Child Component

```
const handleDateChange = (date,value) => {
    setSelectedDate(date);
    props.onChange(value); //setstate
    if(props.setNewDate != undefined)
    {
      setSelectedDate(props.date);   
      props.setNewDate(date);
      props.onChange(a)
    }
  };
};

<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
    <Grid container justify="space-around">
        <ThemeProvider theme={getMuiTheme}>
            <KeyboardDateTimePicker
                value={selectedDate}
                onChange={handleDateChange}
                // onBlur={handleDataBlur}
                // label="Tanggal"
                placeholder="Masukkan Tanggal (Tahun/Bulan/Tanggal)"
                // variant="inline"
                inputVariant="outlined"
                fullWidth
                // onError={console.log}
                format="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm"yyyy
                disablePast
            />
        </ThemeProvider>
    </Grid>
</MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

Parent component

```
    state =  {
      selectedFile: null,
      imagePreviewUrl: null,
      err: null,
      title : '',
      highlight : '',
      platform : '',
      start_publish : '',
      end_publish : '',
      sender : '',
      receiver : '',
      action : '',
      status : '',
      bundle : '',
      initial_date : new Date(),
    };
  setNewDate = (date) => {
        this.setState({ 
          initial_date : date 
        })
      }

onTodoChange(value){
        var start_publish = new Date(this.state.start_publish);
        start_publish.setDate(start_publish.getDate()+(value*30));
        // console.log(start_publish);
        // start_publish.setDate(start_publish.getDate()+(value*30));
        this.setNewDate(start_publish);
        console.log(this.state.initial_date);
      }
      showBundle = (values) => 
      {
        this.setState({
          bundle : JSON.stringify(values),
        }) 
      };

    render()
    {
      let startPublish = new Date(this.state.start_publish);
      let endPublish = new Date(this.state.end_publish);
      let publish = ((endPublish - startPublish) / (60*60*24*1000));
      let $publishInterval = ('');
      if(publish >= 0)
      {
        $publishInterval = (<div class="form-group row mb-4">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Jarak</label>
          <div class="col-sm-4 text-left">
            <span class="form-control text-left">{publish.toFixed(0)} hari</span>
          </div>
          <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Range</label>
          <div class="col-sm-4 text-left">
          <select class="custom-select" onChange={e => this.onTodoChange(e.target.value)} id="platform"> ////// the selector
              <option value="">Select</option>
              <option value={1}>1 Month</option>
              <option value={3}>3 Month</option>
              <option value={6}>6 Month</option>
            </select>
          </div>
      </div>)
      }

      return (
        <Modal
        {...this.props}
        size="lg"
        onExit={this.handleExit}
        backdrop="static"
        animation={true}
        aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
        centered
        >
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} class="was-validated justify-content-center">
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
              Tambah Notifikasi
            </Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body style={{'max-height': 'calc(100vh - 210px)', 'overflow-y': 'auto'}}>

            <div class="form-group row mb-4">
              <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Publish Date</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <MaterialUIPickers required onChange={ (start_publish) => {this.setState( { start_publish })}}></MaterialUIPickers>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row mb-4">
              <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Finish Date</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <MaterialUIPickers required duration={this.state.duration} onChange={ (end_publish) => {this.setState( { end_publish })}}></MaterialUIPickers>
              </div>
            </div>

            {$publishInterval}

            <div class="form-group row mb-4">
              <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Bundle</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                <Provider store={store}>
                  <FieldArraysForm onChange={this.showBundle}/>
                </Provider>
                </div>
            </div>

          </div>

          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button variant="danger" onClick={this.handleExit}>Close</Button>
            <Button variant="success" type="submit">Post</Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </form>
        </Modal>

      )
    }
```

How can I triggered the onchange function of the date picker when I choose the selector?

Comment: what you are looking for.explain more

Comment: i want to change the datetimepicker value by using the dropdown

Comment: like an example if you are selecting 3 Bulan from drop down then what you want to set in your date time picker ???

Comment: yes, if i choose 6 it adds 6 more month from to the datetimepicker value

Comment: add your onTodoChange code as well

Comment: can u give example?

Comment: problem is in your onTodoChange.when you are changing your selection what you are doning in your onTodoChange ???

Comment: i used to set my end_publish state, but it's not changing the value on the text field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your selected value to set new value in your datepicker

```
//use moment to add moths as per your selection 
npm install moment --save 

// 1. add date in your parent state like 

const state = { 
  date : 'your initial date'  // like moment().format('yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm');
 }

//2. add function like 

setNewDate = (date) => {
  this.setState{{ date : date }}
}

// 3. onTodoChange function wich accept value and add moth as per value and set new date to state 

onTodoChange(value){

 const newDate = moment().format('yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm').add(value, 'months').calendar();
 setNewDate(newDate);

}

   // 4. now you can pass it to child component like 

   < Child date={this.state.date} setNewDate={this.setNewDate}  />
```

Now your datepicker will set value as you have updated using your selection

and in your

```
const handleDateChange = (date,value) => {
    setNewDate(date); // set new date 
};
```

You can see when you are selecting any value from select then onTodoChange is called which set new date to state so,state is updated and we are using this date in our child so our child date is also updated

Child Component :

```
const { date , setNewDate } = props;

const handleDateChange = (date,value) => {

     console.log('date',date);
     console.log('value',value);

     setNewDate(date) // if you are getting your date in date / change it to value : this will update your date as you are changing your date in picker 

  };
};

<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
    <Grid container justify="space-around">
        <ThemeProvider theme={getMuiTheme}>
            <KeyboardDateTimePicker
                value={date}        // we are directly using date here 
                onChange={handleDateChange} // will change our date in parent component and we are getting new date here 
                // onBlur={handleDataBlur}
                // label="Tanggal"
                placeholder="Masukkan Tanggal (Tahun/Bulan/Tanggal)"
                // variant="inline"
                inputVariant="outlined"
                fullWidth
                // onError={console.log}
                format="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm"yyyy
                disablePast
            />
        </ThemeProvider>
    </Grid>
</MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

Comment: the problem is the datetimpicker is on the different component. so should i pass the function?

Comment: yes you can. in your parent component you can define your variable like const [date,setDate] = useState( pass initial date ); then you can pass date and setDate as props in your child component

Comment: i have to check your code.how you are passing props and how you are accessing it

Comment: add your parent code as well as child code i'll check

Comment: problem is you are using setState in class based component

Comment: what you can do is.you can define your date in state of parent component and create one function which accept argument as date and set that date to state and pass your date and function as props in your child component

Comment: can i have example?

Comment: wait i'll explain

Comment: update your question with updated code and let me know which is your child component ??

Comment: it works now, but it need to be triggered like opening the calender and click ok, is there any way to do it automatically?

Comment: update your code with new one. please add it in sequense lile parent then child component code.